# Can I Create Advanced SQL Constraints with Embedded Business Logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

If I have table

```
Widget  Version  Latest
XYZ     1.0      0
XYZ     1.1      0
XYZ     1.2      1
ABC     1.0      1
```

Is there a way to create a constraint that says

> each widget-version combination can have any number of 0s for the
>   latest version flag but must have exactly 1 occurrence where the
>   latest flag is 1

?

Or do I have to use a trigger or similar?

Comment: Problem : when you insert a new line (with a Latest version), you'll have to put Latest on 1. For example, `Widget : XYZ`, `Version: 1.3`. So this one must have Latest = 1. But `XYZ / 1.2` must be updated so that Latest = 0, as it's no more the latest value. There's a time when you'll need to either accept two lines with Latest = 1 (by widget) or no one with Latest = 1...

Comment: In my s/p I am removing the latest flag on all existing widget-versions first, which I think keeps to the constraint above.

Comment: Well, when you remove the flag, there's a while when the `must have exactly 1 occurence where the latest flag  is 1` is no more valid...

Comment: You can create a unique filtered index that ensures that there is *at most* 1 occurrence where the latest flag is `1` but, as Raphael says, it's very difficult to maintain a table if the invariant is to be *exactly* one.

Comment: Great point! Thank you. I guess the constraint should be 'at most one combination where latest =1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways (a third one would be to use a View, but it's rather similar to the second solution)

**First**, with a check constraint

Something (this one is ugly, but you've got the idea) :

```
create function [dbo].[checkLatest](@widget varchar(3))
returns bit

as
begin
declare @numOfLatest int;
declare @lastValue int;
declare @maxVersion decimal(18,2);
select @maxVersion = MAX([Version]) from Table1 where Widget = @widget;
--check if there's only one Latest = 1 by Widget
select @numOfLatest = COUNT(*) from Table1 where Widget = @widget and Latest = 1;
--check if Latest = 1 for max version
select @lastValue = Latest from Table1 where [Version] = @maxVersion and Widget = @widget;

return case when @numOfLatest = 1 and @lastValue = 1 then 1 else 0 end
end
GO
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LAtest
    CHECK (checkLatest(Widget) = 1)
```

**CAUTION** : you'll have to deactivate the constraint when you put all your latest flag to 0 in your stored procedure, then reactivate it. You may need to lock your table to avoid any insert / update while constraint is deactivated...

---

**Another way** would be to use a **computed colum**n for `Latest` :

```
create function setLatest(@Widget varchar(3), @Version decimal(18,2))
returns bit
as 
begin
declare @result bit = 0;

with cte as (select  [Version], ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by [Widget] order by [Version] desc) rn from dbo.Table1 where Widget = @Widget)
select @result = case when @Version = [Version] then 1 else 0 end from 
cte where rn = 1
and @Version = [Version]
return @result;
end
```

then drop your Latest column

```
alter table Table1 drop column Latest;
```

and re add it as a computed column

```
alter table Table1 add Latest as setLatest(Widget, [Version]);
```

As it's calculated, it's never gonna be wrong, but... `SELECT` statements will cost more... May depend of the size of your datas.